# Couchbase error: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value

Tags: java, docker, rx-java, couchbase, rx-java2

I have a `Spring-boot` app that saves data to a `Couchbase` server.

I like to save about 500k Students using this code:

```
for (String student: students) {
  ...
  bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create(<unique key here>, TTL, JsonObject.fromJson(studentAsJson)));                
}
```

This works fine for small amount of Students (up to 100K +-).

But whenever app reaches roughly the 110K-140K Student, I get this error:

```
2018-12-23 16:20:57.804 ERROR 17468 --- [nio-8989-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.TemporaryFailureException] with root cause

rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.core.message.kv.UpsertResponse.class
at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.producers.ProducerArbiter.setProducer(ProducerArbiter.java:126) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback$TimeoutMainSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback.java:155) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:103) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:508) ~[core-io-1.7.1.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:86) ~[core-io-1.7.1.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:526) ~[core-io-1.7.1.jar:na]
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

My `Couchbase` is running in `Docker` on the localhost and I wonder if this is some real problem or just limitation due to docker & localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the code reached a "regular" environment, with real DB that runs not inside a container, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 3):

Never worked with CouchBase but it's seems like it's a problem with backpressure(https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)).

So basically your consumer(in this case CouchBase) can't consume the data as fast as you give to it. From what can be seen from the logs you are using RxJava1. I would suggest upgrading to RxJava2. It will need some time because of the changes but you will have access to Flowable(http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html) which offers BackPressure out of the box.

By setting up a Flowable with backpressure you will be able to take care of the problem for slow consumers as it allows you to wait for a consumer to consume the data then send to it the new ones.

If you can't update the version of RxJava this article from David Karnok is worth taking a look as it show ways to deal with this chains without the need for backpresssure: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

Hope this helps.